# result of MapM in haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, ghci

When using mapM in interactive mode:
calling `mapM putStrLn ["random","Text"]`
the output is

> ```
> random
> text
> [(),()]
> ```

however when i call the same function from a script and then run the script:

```
main = do        
    handle <- openFile "todo.txt" ReadMode  
    (tempName, tempHandle) <- openTempFile "." "temp"  
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    let todoTasks = lines contents
        numberedTasks = zipWith (\n line -> show n ++ "-" ++ line) [0..] todoTasks      
    putStrLn "These are your TO-DO items:"  
    mapM putStrLn numberedTasks -- <<<<<<<< HERE <<<<<<<<
    putStrLn "Which one do you want to delete?"     
    numberString <- getLine     
    let number = read numberString     
        newTodoItems = delete (todoTasks !! number) todoTasks     
    hPutStr tempHandle $ unlines newTodoItems  
    hClose handle  
    hClose tempHandle  
    removeFile "todo.txt"  
    renameFile tempName "todo.txt"
```

with the line indicated I do not quite understand why I don't see
`[()..()]` as the output when i run this script; I thought `mapM` does not disregard the result

Comment: The REPL prints results of expressions and `IO` actions, but when you run something normally and don’t use its result, it’s just… unused. It doesn’t get printed or anything.

Comment: Expanding upon @AlexisKing, the REPL more or less does `do { line <- getLine ; print line}`. So since in your code you neither save nor print the result of `mapM` then you will not ever see the `[(),()]`

Comment: Consider using `mapM_`.

Comment: ahh i see, than you! In any case using mapM_ is better since I do not need to build the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought `mapM` does not disregard the result

You thought correctly. It is your code, and not `mapM`, that disregards the result; in particular,

```
do
    mapM putStrLn numberedTasks
    postamble
```

gets desugared to `mapM putStrLn numberedTasks >> postamble`, and `(>>)` disregards the result of its left argument.

> I do not quite understand why i don't see `[()..()]`

Actually, I suspect that what you don't understand is why you *do* see `[(),()]` in GHCi. This is because, although GHCi behaves a little bit like being in a giant `do` block, it is not quite. In particular it tries to show you partial results along the way. So GHCi is doing something special here: it is taking your action, running it, and *additionally* adding a `print` statement for the result of the action.

If you would prefer not to see this printed out, there are several options; probably the best one is to replace `mapM` with `mapM_`; ghci has special code that avoids adding the `print` statement when the result of the `IO` action is `()`.